# Binding to Service Trouble

Tags: android, service

Good Morning All,

I am currently buidling a media player for Android, and I am having trouble binding my player service to an Activity and pulling data from it.  Bear with me...a lot of code follows.

My code---

Interface:

```
interface MyInterface{       
    void playFile( in String file);
    void shuffle ();
    String getPlayingData();

}
```

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public Context context;
    public static String nowPlayingData = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final MyInterface.Stub mBinder = new MyInterface.Stub() {

    public void playFile(String file) throws DeadObjectException {          
       //Song playing method working great!
    }

    public void shuffle()throws DeadObjectException {       
        //This method picks a random song and passes it to nowPlayingData string                
}

    public String getPlayingData() throws RemoteException {

        return nowPlayingData;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    mp.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    mp.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

}

}
```

Main Screen Activity, Shuffle Button:

Service is started in onCreate.  When I click on the shuffle button it uses a method in the service to play a random song, thus setting the nowPlayingData string.

```
public class mainMenu extends Activity {


private MyInterface mInterface;
    private ServiceToken mToken;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent startedSvc = new Intent(mainMenu.this, MyService.class);
    boolean success = this.bindService(
            startedSvc, svcConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);      
    this.startService(startedSvc);

    findViewById(R.id.shuffle).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


                try {
        sInterface.shuffle();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent play_screen = new Intent(MyPlayer.getContext(), NowPlaying.class);                   
            startActivity(play_screen);

            }
```

Player Activity:

I want to bind to the service, and pull nowPlayingData over using the interfaces getPlayingData method.

```
public class NowPlaying extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public static String nowPlayingData = null;
MyInterface mInterface;
boolean isConnected = false;
RemoteServiceConnection conn = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.now_playing);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    Log.i("Log", "Player Loaded");

    bindService();
    getData();
    fillView();             
}   


public void fillView(){      
    //This method needs the nowPlayingData string to update the view                
}



class RemoteServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, 
     IBinder boundService ) {
mInterface = MyInterface.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)boundService);
isConnected = true;
            Log.d("Now Playing", "Service Connected" );             
      }

      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            sInterface = null;
       // updateServiceStatus();
            isConnected = false;
        Log.d( getClass().getSimpleName(), "onServiceDisconnected" );
        getData();
      }
};



private void bindService() {

if(conn == null) {
    conn = new RemoteServiceConnection();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.musicplayer.MyPlayer", "com.musicplayer.MyPlayer.MyService");
    bindService(i, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d( getClass().getSimpleName(), "bindService()" );
 } else {
   Toast.makeText(NowPlaying.this, "Cannot bind - service already bound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}

private void getData() {
 if(conn == null) {
     Log.i("getData", "No Connection");
 } else {
    try {
       String data = mInterface.getPlayingData();  
       Log.i("Data Recieved", data);
       Log.d( getClass().getSimpleName(), "invokeService()" );
    } catch (RemoteException re) {
       Log.e( getClass().getSimpleName(), "RemoteException" );
    }
  }
 }   

}
```

I have been studying many examples online, and perhaps my mish-mash of attempts has caused this to not work.  My code works all the way through to binding the service, but OnServiceConnected is never called, and conn remains null.

Any help you guys can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will not make re-entrant event calls to your activity, so onServiceConnected can't be called until onCreate has returned

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot start any activity that pertains to the service prior to onCreate returns?  Not sure where I should move the fillView in that case.

Comment: You cannot do anything that depends on the service being connected until after you've returned from onCreate so that onServiceConnected can be called.  You may be able to trigger your later tasks off some existing event, or off of on ServiceConnected, or you can use a timer to fire them a short time later (and decide something is wrong if the service hasn't connected by then)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I managed to get this working by adding the methods to the onServiceConnected.